# Nodejs Selenium-webdriver 2 drivers but only 1 gets controlled

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created a class, that contains a start function that creates a selenium driver and reloads (just for testing), example:

```
class TestDriver{
    async start(){
        //Create driver
        var driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome');
        .build();


        setTimeout(() => {
            await driver.get('https://google.com');
        }, 1000)
    }

}
```

When i create 2 classes of the TestDriver, example:

```
var test1 = new TestDriver();
test1.start();

var test2 = new TestDriver();
test2.start();
```

Only 1 of the drivers/windows refresh, it seems like even doe 2 drivers are created both classes are only controlling one of them.

Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your second instance name is `test2` while you're trying to handle `test12`... Is it typo?

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks for notifying me!